# How update a attribute column jsonb Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Hi this is my column campos of type jsonb in postgres

```
{"lista": [{"valor": "cabibajo", "nombre": "Nro. DE SERIE"}, {"valor": "", "nombre": "Nro. DE PLACA"}, {"valor": "", "nombre": "Nro. de ATM"}]}
```

I have many records with same value of nombre atribute, So I need to replace all value of attribute nombre = Nro. DE SERIE, Nro. DE PLACA, Nro. de ATM, with new data example "Nro Telephone"

This is my query for select all records concide

```
SELECT "proyectos".* FROM "proyectos"
 WHERE campos @>  '{"lista": [{"nombre": "Nro. DE SERIE"}]}'
 OR campos @> '{"lista": [{"nombre": "Nro. DE PLACA"}]}'
 OR campos @> '{"lista": [{"nombre": "Nro. de ATM"}]}'
```

Please any help me